# URL Rewriting in .net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

We have current .net page structure like this with URL forming like this..

http://www.example.com/pages/login.aspx?q=1234

and want to convert this to

http://www.example.com/login?q=1234

How to bypass Pages directory with url rewrite or filtering..

Also we would like to ignore this rule for files like ashx/css/js/png/jpegs/axd etc...

Any help would be appreciated ..

Comment: which is the .net framework you are using? read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Comment: also specify your IIS version.